# Solspace Facebook Connect passive registration use email as username so it matches User

Tags: solspace, solspace-user, solspace-facebookconnect

I'm using Solspace Users as well as Facebook Connect.

For all new member registrations through User I have username set to always use email address.

I'm also creating new members with passive registration through Facebook Connect's login button. However, when members are registered passively it looks like the username is being automatically created based on screen name with underscores, rather than using the email address.

I want all members, including those created with FBC's passive registration, to use email as username - otherwise if someone logs in with facebook and then later tries to login with email and password, they won't be able to login the traditional way because their username is not properly set as their email address.

**What do I change in FBC to get it to behave this way, so that passive registrations have the same format as if they were manual registrations through User?**

Comment: The whole point of FBC passive registration is for users to never have to deal with an EE account's username and password. Even the password is a hash generated by FB/FBC, which the users wouldn't know, and wouldn't need to know since they used passive registration.

Comment: Yes I agree. BUT, after using this for less than two weeks I've already had one member try to sign in using email and password after they first signed in with facebook, and then they got frustrated when their email address wasn't found. If the username and email fields were setup to match that of the User registered member, than at least if they reset their password they could login the traditional way. I'm not saying this is the behaviour I want or expect, but it's already happening so I'm trying to address the situation to avoid future problems.

Comment: Unfortunately having email as a username when registering through FBC isn't possible. I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on.
http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions

Comment: Thanks I've submitted the feature request to your forum.